# Unicorn cannot allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

i need your help!

I have deployed my Rails app in Ubuntu 12.04, using Nginx, MySQL, Solr and Unicorn.

Every mentioned service is started, instead of unicorn, which says following:

> I, [2013-02-11T16:10:20.187989 #27547]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
>   I, [2013-02-11T16:10:52.159198 #27547]  INFO -- : unlinking existing
>   socket=/var/www/staging/shared/unicorn.sock I,
>   [2013-02-11T16:10:52.159488 #27547]  INFO -- : listening on
>   addr=/var/www/staging/shared/unicorn.sock fd=12 E,
>   [2013-02-11T16:10:52.161513 #27547] ERROR -- : Cannot allocate memory
>   - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM) /var/www/staging/shared/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:496:in
>   `fork'
>   /var/www/staging/shared/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:496:in`
>   spawn_missing_workers'
>   /var/www/staging/shared/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in
>   `start'
>   /var/www/staging/shared/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.5.0/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in`
>   '
>   /var/www/staging/shared/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
>   /var/www/staging/shared/gems/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in`
>   '

VDS has 1.5Gb of RAM and it's enough for unicorn:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

> ```
> MemTotal:        1585152 kB
> MemFree:          989580 kB
> Cached:           425296 kB
> Active:           348504 kB
> Inactive:         175356 kB
> Active(anon):      98488 kB
> Inactive(anon):       76 kB
> Active(file):     250016 kB
> Inactive(file):   175280 kB
> Unevictable:           0 kB
> Mlocked:               0 kB
> SwapTotal:        204800 kB
> SwapFree:         204800 kB
> Dirty:                12 kB
> Writeback:             0 kB
> AnonPages:         98564 kB
> Shmem:              3604 kB
> Slab:              71680 kB
> SReclaimable:      66144 kB
> SUnreclaim:         5536 kB
> ```

I have unicorn_rails v4.5.0

Unicorn starts by following command:

`bundle exec unicorn_rails -c /var/www/staging/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D`

What i'm doing wrong here?

---

Hmm, i remembered, that previously i had following strange error:

```
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-1.9.3-p327' -c 'cd /var/www/staging/current && bundle exec unicorn_rails -c /var/www/staging/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D'"
```

Maybe it is somehow related to memory problems…

Comment: Been having the same problem occasionally.  Reducing my unicorn workers seems to help but haven't solved it.

Comment: @AntonAL, how many workers are you trying to start?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but here's a link to one of my projects that starts up unicorn on Ubuntu 12.04 https://github.com/cyrusstoller/revtilt

Answer (score 2):

It seems the error is happening when forking new processes. You may need to reduce the workers in your config/unicorn.rb file. Each worker is a process and each process loads the application environment into the RAM.